# how to download file and store in downloads folder in vue.js and laravel5.4

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.4

I have one button called View Resume. When the user clicks on the button i want to download the resume and store it in the downloads folder.

I stored the resume in my table. I just want to download it by using vue.js

I already search in google. But i didn't find any correct results.

here is my button:

```
<ElButton  type="success"
           size="small">
  Resume
</ElButton>
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Please tell us how your `resume` is stored. Only a path to the file ? Or the actual file itself. What is the expected download result ?

Comment: are you using laravel for REST API or laravel + vue?

Comment: @jogesh_pi i am using laravel+vue

Comment: @FrankProvost i have a table in that i have column called resume..there i can store resume as content..so in another page i gave option called resume..here i want to download that resume..

Comment: but what is the expected outcome? a pdf? a plain text? a docx? does the table column contain a simple text ? is it binary?

Comment: table column has simpel text..i am expecting docx

Comment: you expect a docx download from a simple string? then you will need to parse it to a doxc file first. You'll find packages for that. Usually they also provide a sample on how to download it after parsing. You'll need a route, a corresponding controller method and then simply link the button to open the route in a new tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In vour vue component:

```
...
<button @click="getResume">Download resume</button>
...

methods: {
   ...

   getResume() {
       ...code to perform a request to the api...
   }
}
```

In your API controller:

```
... code to get the path to the correct resume ...

return response()->download('...path to resume file...');
```

Comment: how should i give this link in my vue.js button?

Comment: Create a function in your component that makes a `GET` request to the appropriate endpoint?

Comment: sorry i can't understand..can you please explain a little bit more?

Comment: ok..fine..in that getresume() method..what things we have to do..to get the resume

Comment: @bharathi this isn't a website for tutorials, we're here to answer technical questions, you're going to have to put some effort in yourself if you want to understand basics.